# A question about "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.typing'"

Tags: python, numpy, annotations

I am trying to import [ArrayLike](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/typing.html#numpy.typing.ArrayLike) doing `from numpy.typing import ArrayLike`, and I get the error mentioned in the title:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.typing'`

I know I could simply write `import numpy.typing as npt` as the documentation shows, but I would like the simplicity of just importing the types that I want to use. It is also not the first time that this has happened to me: I want to import a specific method/class but I'm forced to import the parent module with a nickname instead because otherwise, I get an Error. Why's that?

Comment: I triggered the same issue, but only on python 3.6 - Numpy version is 1.19.5.
older Python versions might require the typing-extension. https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/
Which version did you use?

Comment: I just found out, that the numpy typing module was introduced in numpy 1.20

Comment: Problem solved with `%pip install -U numpy` to get version 1.21.1 instead of 1.19.5 on Google Colab.

Comment: and the numpy upgrade should be as early as possible in the notebook ([ref](https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/issues/2830))

Comment: They broke the API. Not possible without upgrading. Is broken.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Re-posting the resolution in the comments above as a community wiki for better visibility:

> The numpy typing module was introduced in numpy 1.20

Make sure that you have the correct `numpy` version by running the following at the beginning of your notebook:

```
%pip install -U numpy
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, my version of `numpy` was correct but I could not get rid of the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typing'
```

What helped was to directly import the module at the top of the file:

```
import numpy.typing
```

Then I was able to use either `numpy.typing.ArrayLike` or `np.typing.ArrayLike`.

Comment: I had the same problem, seems to be related to some internal processing. But you can also directly import ArrayLike etc with

from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

then you can also mark these as optional with if typing.TYPE_CHECKING